# JQM multi-select dismiss not firing pagebeforeshow event

Tags: android, events, drop-down-menu, jquery-mobile

I have this problem with a JQM multi-select box. On a browser, when I open the select list, the source page is completely hidden behind the dialog - when I dismiss the dialog, I use the *pagebeforeshow* event on the source page to read the selections. This works fine in the browser, but in the phone, if the select list is small, it does not hide the source page and the *pagebeforeshow* event never gets fired. To test this, I made a larger list of options and in this case the source page is completely hidden behind the dialog. When the dialog is dismissed, the *pagebeforeshow* event fires correctly. 
My use of the *pagebeforeshow* was to try and get around not having a dismiss event on the dialog that I can hook into... so two questions:

1. is there an event I can hook into? I looked around the net and in SO
   and none of the solutions suggested seem to work for me, or for a
   (multi)select box.
2. is there some way I can force the dialog to
   always open in full screen mode on the device?

Correction:
The same behaviour is in the browser - just didn't have a small enough list when I tested...

One more thing - the placeholder does not show when the select page is maximised - only when it is a small popup...(on chrome and android)
Correction: in maxmized mode, only the 'delete' icon appears - there is no placeholder text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it in two ways, and both involved removing the header div.

For the full page dialog:

```
$("body").on("pagebeforeshow", "#filter-dialog", function(){
    $(this).find("div.ui-header").remove();
});
```

and for the popup dialog:

```
$("#my-page").on('pagebeforeshow', function(event){
    $("#filter-listbox").find("div.ui-header").remove();
});
```

HTH someone someday...